# pushState staying on the same page

Tags: html, routes, pushstate

I'm trying to wrap my head around using HTML5 pushState. It seems to work great. I can add states, go back with my browser and everything looks fine. However, when I refresh the page, it leads to a 404, because the URL that was appended with pushState doesn't actually exist...

I am trying to get everything to load from a single folder with an `index.html` page, so the URL would look something like `http://www.server.com/app_name/<something>` (`app_name` is a folder with an index.html file).

As far as I could gather, hashbang is considered bad, so **what pushState URLs can / should I use that will stay on the same actual page and allow me to refresh?**

And after refreshing, would I still be able to retrieve the state?

p.s. I am not concerned about browsers without javascript enabled or maintaining backwards compatibility. I do not want to change any `.htaccess` rules to make this portable and configuration-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up on pushState, and instead used [BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) jQuery plugin.

The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // making sure a hashchange event is triggered for refresh
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});

// this gets called on any page change, back button etc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
  // the fragment contains a hash value at the
  // end of the url, e.g. #xyz
  var url = $.param.fragment();
  // simulating a click on the appropriate link on the page
  // based on the fragment
  $('.panel a[href="#' + url + '"]').click()
});
```

URLs on the page are in this format:

```
<a href="#xyz">link to xyz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your web server tries to locate a file called *something* in your *app_name* folder. What you must do is route all requests to /app_name/* to your index.html and then set the appropriate application state using the location object of the DOM.

You won't get far without telling the server what it should do. That's the whole point of the History API. If you don't want to mess with .htaccess files you probably should edit the configuration of your web server (Apache?) using mod_rewrite or sth. like that.

Comment: yes, this is the problem I'm trying to solve, without tweaking server routes / .htaccess rules.